# How to blocks icmp echo requests from a subnet

Tags: iptables

On my linux box I've 2 NICS:

```
br0 192.168.1.0/24 (192.168.1.1 server)
eth1 192.168.2.0/24 lan1
eth2 192.168.3.0/24 lan2
[...]
```

there's a routing from eth1 to br0 and also from eth2 to br0

I droppped icmp echo requests on eth1 from same subnet:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p  icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j DROP
```

but I also want blocks icmp echo requests ONLY from 192.168.2.0/24 network on 192.168.1.1.

So I don't want that clients on 192.168.2.0/24 can ping 192.168.1.1

Comment: Note this is a very narrow question, without further information it suggests stock `nmap` host discovery will still work.  https://nmap.org/book/man-host-discovery.html

Answer (score 0):

check `man iptables`:

> [!] -s, --source address[/mask][,...]

`-s 192.168.2.0/24` affect the whole subnet.

Comment: doesn't run. I just tried

Comment: @Pol `--icmp-type` is part of `iptables-extensions`. You may need to add `-m` option to use extension.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the source IP or subnet with "-s" and the destination IP or subnet with "-d"
Below a sample rule

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.2.0/24 -d 192.168.1.1/32 -p icmp -m hashlimit --hashlimit-upto 3/sec --hashlimit-burst 5 --hashlimit-mode srcip,dstip --hashlimit-name xticmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j DROP

iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.2.0/24 -d 192.168.1.1/32 -p icmp -m hashlimit --hashlimit-upto 3/sec --hashlimit-burst 5 --hashlimit-mode srcip,dstip --hashlimit-name xticmp -m icmp --icmp-type 30 -j DROP
```